# Monacaでニフティクラウドに絵文字を登録することは可能か知りたいです

Tags: javascript, html, monaca

**したいこと**
Monacaでニフティクラウドに絵文字を登録したいです。

**試したこと**
1.まずは普通に絵文字を入力→登録処理
→空白が登録される

2.絵文字を入力→Unicodeに変換→登録処理
→同じく空白が登録される

**聞きたいこと**
Monacaからニフティクラウドに絵文字を登録することは可能か。
可能ならその方法。

**HTML**

```
<button id="btRegister" type="button">登録</button>
<span class="contentHide" id="emojiForm">
    <label for="status0">仕事：</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="statusJob" id="status0"><br>
    <label for="status1">休み：</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="statusJob" id="status1"><br>
    <label for="status2">テレワーク：</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="statusJob" id="status2"><br>
    <label for="statusother">その他：</label>
    <input type="text" id="statusother"><br>
    <input type="text" class="statusJob" id="status3"><br>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
    //登録ボタンクリック時の処理
    document.querySelector("#btRegister").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var ncmb = new NCMB("###","###");
        var ListEmoji = ncmb.DataStore("listEmoji");
    
        var statusElements = document.getElementsByClassName('statusJob');
        var statusOther = document.getElementById('statusother').value;
        var emojiCode;
        var status = "";
            
        for (var i = 0; i < statusElements.length; i++) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    status = "仕事";
                    break;
                case 1:
                        status = "休み";
                        break;
                case 2:
                    status = "テレワーク";
                    break;
                default:
                    status = "その他";
                    break;
            }
            //emojiCode = toUnicode(statusElements[i].value); // emojiCode の値を代入
            emojiCode = toUnicode(document.getElementById("status" + i).value);
            if (emojiCode !== "" && emojiCode !== null && emojiCode !== undefined) {
                 ListEmoji.equalTo('status', status)
                    .fetch()
                    .then(function(result) {
                    if (result.length > 0) {
                        result[0].set('emojiCode', emojiCode);
                        result[0].update();
                    } else {
                        var listEmoji = new ListEmoji();
                        listEmoji.set('status', status);
                        listEmoji.set('emojiCode', emojiCode);
                        listEmoji.save();
                    }
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.error('データの保存中にエラーが発生しました:', error);
                    });
                }
        }
    });

    function toUnicode(str) {
    return Array.from(str).map(char => "\\u" + char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, "0")).join("");
    }
```